# iframe-resizer: ScrollTo() works, but ScrollToOffset() does not

Tags: iframe, iframe-resizer

I'm running iframe resizer 3.5.3 on a wordpress installation. I can't say I really know what I'm doing, but I did a lot of reading and googling online, and got iframe-resizer up and running.

My iframe is embedded in the middle of the page, so I used `scrollTo()` to get it to scroll down to the iframe. See code below:

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="/wp-content/uploads/iframeresizer/iframeResizer.min.js"></script> 
 <script type="text/javascript">
      iFrameResize( { minHeight : 1000, log : true, InPageLinks : true,   
      initCallback: function() { scrollTo(0,1000); }                                 
      } );
 </script>
```

This worked, but `scrollToOffset()` did not. I can't figure out why one should work while the other does not. Here is the code:

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="/wp-content/uploads/iframeresizer/iframeResizer.min.js"></script> 
 <script type="text/javascript">
      iFrameResize( { minHeight : 1000, log : true, InPageLinks : true,   
      initCallback: function() { scrollToOffset(1,1); }                                 
      } );
 </script>
```

Any reason why one should work while the other doesn't? Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The two methods should be called from inside the iFrame, not from the callbacks.

scrollTo works because you are calling the native `window.scrollTo` method, rather than the iframeResizer one.